# How to pass image url to line_items.images field in Stripe API in django

Tags: python, django, image, django-models, stripe-payments

In my project i'm trying to buy products and uses Stripe api for payment.So during payment time i would like to display `product.name`,`product.price` and `product.image` in the session. `product.name` and `product.price` works fine but instead of `product.image` alt section of the image (alt='product') is displaying.

class in views.py

```
class CreateCheckoutSessionView(View):
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    product_id = self.kwargs['id']
    product = cake_list.objects.get(id = product_id)
    YOUR_DOMAIN = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000'
    checkout_session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
        payment_method_types=['card'],
        line_items=[
            {
                'price_data': {
                    'currency': 'usd',
                    'unit_amount': product.price*100,
                    'product_data': {
                        'name': product.name ,
                        'images': [YOUR_DOMAIN +'/media/'+ str(product.image)],
                    },
                },
                'quantity': 1,
            },
        ],
        mode='payment',
        success_url=YOUR_DOMAIN + '/myorders/',
        cancel_url=YOUR_DOMAIN + '/payment-cancelled/',
    )
    return JsonResponse({
        'id' : checkout_session.id
    })
```

While printing `product.image` in console it displays the correct ImageField data which is `images/filename.png`. 'images' is the file which images are `upload_to`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to fully understand the issue here, but my first guess would be that you're attempting to pass image URLs from your local machine (`http://127.0.0.1:8000`) which are inaccessible from the remote Stripe Checkout URL.

Stripe Checkout is a fully hosted solution, once you redirect to the created Checkout session you're no longer working inside of your local development environment (see the redirected URL in your browser). To remedy this, you should pass URLs for your product images that are hosted remotely (on a CDN, for example) that the Checkout session can access.